# Хранение данных по городам

Tags: mongodb

Есть очень много данных по городам, и городов тоже очень много. Хранить все в одной коллекции и сделать индекс я думаю этого будет мало. Так как будет нужно использовать не один индекс. Есть какие нибудь другие возможности ? разбивка на партиции и т.д Так как будет много родов создавать для каждого города коллекцию я думаю это плохо.  Спасибо!

Comment: [По итогам переписи 2010 года 1100 населённых пунктов имеют статус города](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Считаете это много?

Answer (score 1):

1. Каждый географический item имеет свой тип. Храните все в одной таблице с линкой каждого итема на своего родителя.

Индексы делайте по конкретному типу и по родителю.

Например:

В Беларуси есть такая деревня как "Париж". У нее свой тип.
Во Франции есть город Париж. Тип "город" более приоритетен, чем тип "Деревня".

Сорри, может я плохо понял вопрос, но рассказал как это делается у меня. P.S. Размер БД с координатами картографий - 32Гб. ПРямой/обратный геокоддинг выполняется за тысячные секунды.